# Section Access In Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

GOAL:

-To allow the manager to only view the all projects in qlikview, and not edit anything.

-Team members can only see data from projects they are in

CONDITIONS:

-Joe(Team member) can only see data from his projects only.

-Bob(Manager) can see data from all projects in the team, however he cannot edit or make changes to them.

In this scenario, there is only 1 manager, an admin, and many team members.

So I guess the process would be:

1. Check who the user is (Not sure what to use here. Username/password? Ideally it would be the company email, but don't know if this is possible)
2. Once it knows who the user is, checks if said person can access the document
3. If they do have access, it decides what can be accessed. (if manager, can only view all projects, if team member, can only view certain projects)
4. Display the dashboard.

Right now, the QVW file gets data from a database using OLEDB connection.

Sorry I've only been introduced to Qlikview about a week ago and I've been tasked to get this done so any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot about QV section access around.

Think your scenario is possible to be achieved using section access. Please read https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-1853 for more detailed explanation of section access methods.

Warning: **Always have copy of the document without section access!** 
Just to be sure you are not locked out of the document because if this happens there is no way to open the document